# How to make /dev/sdf?

Tags: linux, usb-drive

On a server I have 5 disks (boot-disks + 4 disks in RAID, sda-sde). Now I need to connect a new disk using a PATA/USB-adapter. I do not have a `/dev/sdf`, so the USB-device is not found at all and cannot be seen in `lsusb`.

The adapter works fine in a laptop with only one disk - there it's found under `/dev/sdb`.

So; how do I create `/dev/sdf` so the adapter + disk can be found?

Comment: Typically devices are created automatically by udev. If this doesn't work it often means that the device is not detected by the kernel. Check the kernel messages via `dmesg`, maybe you have to load another module or your kernel has different configure options or a port on your server is defect

Comment: @UlrichDangel You should post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Typically devices are autoamtically created by udev. If this doesn't work, it often means that the device is not detected by the kernel. Check the kernel messages via `dmesg`, maybe you have to load another module or your kernel has different options or a port on your server is defect.